# @RequestParam Spring 4.0 -> 4.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am noticing that Spring changed the way RequestParam marshals parameters to Controller end points in Spring 4.2. Namely when I have something like:

```
public String myEndpoint(@RequestParam List<String> strings) {
   ...
}
```

Previously HTML input elements that were sent with their `value` attribute being blank would be included in the list as null. In 4.2 instead they are the empty string.'

Some examples:

```
/myEndpoint?strings=
```

results in empty list.

```
/myEndpoint?string=a&string=
```

results in `["a", ""]` whereas it used to be `["a", null]`

I see in the release notes that the behavior for @RequestParam was indeed changed from 4.0 to 4.2. Is there an easy way to make a new class or extend RequestParam to work like it used to so I don't have to change any controller logic?

For example instead of Spring 4.2 RequestParam:

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface RequestParam {

    @AliasFor("name")
    String value() default "";

    @AliasFor("value")
    String name() default "";

    boolean required() default true;

    String defaultValue() default ValueConstants.DEFAULT_NONE;

}
```

Make my own annotation to mimic Spring 4.0:

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface MyRequestParam {

    String value() default "";

    boolean required() default true;

    String defaultValue() default ValueConstants.DEFAULT_NONE;

}
```

Is this the easiest way forward?

EDIT:

So it seems the above approach does not work. It fail with a "Cannot instantiate List" error so I guess Spring is looking specifically for RequestParam to do its work.

Comment: I'm not in a position to test this, but have you thought passing `""` to Spring's annotation?

Comment: @Makoto Not sure what you mean by that. Could you provide a code sample/

Answer (score 1):

Although there was a change in the behavior of `@RequestParam`, I don't believe that is the cause of the problem you have.

- All the attributes of the `@RequestParam` annotation pertain only to the argument it annotates, the `List<String> strings` in your case. It has nothing to do with the actual elements/values of the `List`.

If you look at `RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver`, which resolves the `@RequestParam` argument, Request parameters are added to the `List<String>` as they appear in the raw request object:

```
String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(name);
if (paramValues != null) {
    arg = (paramValues.length == 1 ? paramValues[0] : paramValues);
}

...

return arg;
```

**Possible Solution**
It appears that the argument is converted from a `String[]` to a `List<String>` via the `CustomCollectionEditor` that is registered by default. You could add a custom editor to configure its functionality so that every empty string in the `String[]`/request parameters ends up as `null` in your `List<String>`.

1. Extend the `CustomCollectionEditor` and override the `convertElement(Object)` method:

   ```
   MyCollectionEditor extends CustomCollectionEditor {

       @Override
       protected Object convertElement(Object element) {
           if(element instanceof String) {
               element = (String) element;
               // "" will be null
               element = (element.isEmpty()) ? null : element;
           }

           return element;
   }
   ```
2. Add the editor to the binder in your @InitBinder method in your controller.

   ```
   @InitBinder
   public void myBinder(DataBinder binder) {
       //...

       binder.registerCustomEditor(...);

       //...
   }
   ```

Let me know if this works for you!